# ChartJS Donut chart but with a tick

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to create a donut chart with a tick and I'm not sure how to go about it. Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

I know I can create a half donut by doing the following:

```
options: {
    rotation: 1 * Math.PI,
    circumference: 1 * Math.PI
}
```

But as for the black tick line representing 98.4%? How would I do that?

Comment: Is the tick representing the whole value of green area or only the value of the area where the tick is placed?

Comment: It's representing only the value of the area where the tick is placed.

Comment: you can go through this discussion to find a solution: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2874

Comment: Awesome find, thank you so much!